# Typo3 8.7.24 Scheduler is doing nothing

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-8.x

could not find an answer here, therefore I ask it :-)

Using Typo3 8.7.24 and want to use scheduler for removing delete db entries (recycler). I made the task and executed it manually.
Result is: nothing is done. Recylcer still shows the deleted entries.

Does somebody have an idea why this is not working?

BR
Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the scheduler task correctly?

Aside from the configuration how often the task should be executed you need to configure:

- "Delete entries older than (in days)"
  how long ago should a deletion have occurred so that the record can be removed?
- "Tables"
  which tables should be considered to clean up?

Either your deletion wasn't that long ago or your records do not belong to any monitored table.

Comment: HI Bernd, the tables are in the list, days are set correct and I do only start the schedule manually, so nothing wrong so far.

Comment: The only part of the scheduler which is working on my site is the task to update the repository extension list.

Comment: There is a garbage task to delete the entries in sys_log. This is also not working. It seems there is a mayor problem here, either in the module or on my server. 
So strange is, that the task is not giving some error, jsut the green box appears and says task executed.

Comment: do you have any errors? check for returned errorlevel or view errorlog

Comment: No errors, always green box. Which log file would indicate erros which mayb occured and not shown in the Backend view?

Comment: in tyypo3temp/var/logs/ there is nothing indicating errors

Comment: Additional info: Running php 7.1.27 and Typo 8.7.24

Comment: have you enabled development mode? otherwise nearly all error messages are suppressed. You also may [execute your scheduler task by hand from the command shell](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/8.7/Installation/SchedulerShellScript/)

Comment: Hi Bernd, i migth be wrong for the value older than. but have to wait till tomorrow, because I do not have entries older than one day at the moment (I deleted older stuff directly in the database).

Comment: Bernd, my fault. Really made a mistake with the older than value. It is working.